# Questions regarding XML request format

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following code from Ben Nadel's post:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soap:Body>

<Subscriber.AddAndResubscribe
xmlns="http://api.createsend.com/api/">

<ApiKey>#campaignMonitorKey#</ApiKey>
<ListID>#campaignMonitorList#</ListID>
<Email>kim@sweet-n-sassy.com</Email>
<Name></Name>

</Subscriber.AddAndResubscribe>

</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I understood that AddAndResubscribe is the operation name and Subscriber.AddandResubscribe is the input name. I am wondering what does campaignMonitorKey, campaignMonitorList , the value in the Email tag and an empty Name tag means? Could anyone please explain?

Source for WSDL: http://api.createsend.com/api/api.asmx?WSDL

Source for the POST: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-Making-SOAP-Web-Service-Requests-With-ColdFusion-And-CFHTTP.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Ben Nadel's post, he's sending data to Campaign Monitor's newsletter subscription API. The structure of the soap body is dictated in this case by Campaign Monitor. What is being passed are the values needed to use their addAResubscribe method.

Since I don't use Campaign Monitor, I'm only making an educated guess here:

ApiKey: I'm assuming is an authentication key you gain when you sign up. This allows Campaign Monitor know who is sending the request, and that the customer is still active. Notice that `#campaignMonitorKey#`. This value would be set else were in the application. Since it's Ben's ApiKey, the setting of this value was left out of his example.

ListID: would be the ID representing a mailing lists. Once again, this would be set else were in the application, and wasn't shared in the example.

Email: the email being added.

Name would be the name of the person reviving the email.

When consuming soap request myself, I first use an application called [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org). This tool can generate sample request bodys for all the methods exposed by the WSDL URL. From here you can try putting in your own values and get a response back.